# Square brackets are causing SQL syntax error for ArcPy SelectLayerByAttribute

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have been trying to use ArcPy’s SelectLayerByAttribute funciton and I can get it to work with this code:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("LAYER", "NEW_SELECTION", "OBJECTID=11111")
```

But I have some rows with spaces in the name, so I need to add brackets around the field names for the SQL to work correctly. But for some reason it is throwing a SQL syntax error whenever I try to add in the brackets. So if I try something like this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("LAYER", "NEW_SELECTION", "[OBJECT ID]=11111")
```

I get this error:

> An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT objectid FROM LAYER WHERE
> [OBJECT ID] = 111111]

Any idea why this is happening or how I could fix it?

Comment: Brackets are not supported by most storage formats. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the format used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the real field name, because ArcGIS doesn't accept field name with blank spaces.

Try with underscore instead.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("LAYER", "NEW_SELECTION", "[OBJECT_ID]=11111")
```

Blank spaces only accepted in Alias